# How can I configure mailgun in localhost

Tags: localhost

I'm a rookie and I'm trying an application that I made in Laravel 5.8 and I'm interested in sending mail, but right now I'm local, that is, in localhost. It is possible to send mail in localhost for testing. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, on a *nix system a local mail service (typically `/usr/bin/sendmail`) is used for things like cron output, alerts, etc.

You may or may not need to do a configuration of a MTA (mail transport agent).  Simply set it up "for local delivery only".

I'm on Debian and Ubuntu and Mint, and `alpine` works fine as a (minimal command line) mail client and `exim4` works great for the `sendmail` portion, and the `exim4` package does a nice autoconfig that has a "local only" set up choice.